# UWP C# - Why does NotifyPropertyChanged not fire in this scenario?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, getter-setter, inotifypropertychanged

In the following scenario, NotifyPropertyChanged does not fire, thus my UI doesn't update (simplified view-model shown):

```
public class NetworkGraphViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

     private String byteSentSpeed { get; set; }

     public String ByteSentSpeed { get { return byteSentSpeed; } set { byteSentSpeed = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ByteSentSpeed"); } }

     private void MyEvent(object sender, object eventArgs)
     {
         byteSentSpeed = byteSentSpeed + 5;
     }

     public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
     {
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
             PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }

}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Margin="30,5,10,5"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="bytesSentSpeedBlock" Text="{Binding ByteSentSpeed}"/>
```

...whereas the following example DOES update the UI:

```
public class NetworkGraphViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

     private String byteSentSpeed { get; set; }

     public String ByteSentSpeed { get { return byteSentSpeed; } set { byteSentSpeed = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ByteSentSpeed"); } }

     private void MyEvent(object sender, object eventArgs)
     {
         byteSentSpeed = byteSentSpeed + 5;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("ByteSentSpeed")
     }

     public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
     {
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
             PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }

}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Margin="30,5,10,5"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="bytesSentSpeedBlock" Text="{Binding ByteSentSpeed}"/>
```

Maybe I'm incorrect in assuming that the change would propagate into the public variable "ByteSentSpeed" through the value assigned to "byteSentSpeed"?

Is this really the most efficient way to do this, or am I doing something stupid?

Comment: _"am I doing something stupid?"_ -- you said it, not me. _"Maybe I'm incorrect in assuming that the change would propagate into the public variable "ByteSentSpeed" through the value assigned to "byteSentSpeed"?"_ -- yes, this. Why'd the `ByteSentSpeed` property setter get called just because you assigned a new value to the backing field? Since the setter itself sets the backing field, if the setter was called automatically when the field got set, there'd be no way to implement a property; you'd always get an infinite recursion. Set the property value instead of the field: `ByteSentSpeed += 5;`

Comment: Has Peter’s reply solved your confusion? @PeterDuniho Are you willing to make your comment as an answer?

Comment: Yep. I don't know why I couldn't wrap my head around this one until now, especially since I noticed the stack overflow error earlier. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`byteSentSpeed` and `ByteSentSpeed` are two different properties. Setting the former won't invoke the setter of the latter which raises the `PropertyChanged` event.

And `byteSentSpeed` should be a backing *field* rather than a property:

```
 private String byteSentSpeed;
 public String ByteSentSpeed { get { return byteSentSpeed; } set { byteSentSpeed = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ByteSentSpeed"); } }
```

You should set the *property* whenever you want to update the UI:

```
private void MyEvent(object sender, object eventArgs)
{
    ByteSentSpeed = ByteSentSpeed + 5;
}
```